# Asp.net core mvc role-based authorization with Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory, user-roles

So, I have Asp.net core MVC app with Azure AD that allows people to sing in with their microsoft acc and then gives me their name and email. I have this authorization that is based on one static class that adds user on Index page and its so dumb, so I want to switch to role-based authorization. My problem is that I was unable to find any info about how to do it. Is there some type of tutorial? I am very new to authorization so I really dont know how these things work but I am unable to find some source... Thanks for any help.

Edit: I want user to sing in with his microsoft acc and then get his name, look to db and then add him roles.

Comment: Hi if you are looking for a Role-based authorization you need to handle the roles in the Azure AD please go through the below answer. If you are looking for only sign in authorization with Microsoft account and validate the user with your local Database and based on the information if need to assign roles to the user then you need to go with the Azure AD B2C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles) which helps you to add authorization using app roles & roles claims to an ASP.NET Core web app that's signs-in users with the Microsoft identity platform.

Comment: Is there a DIRECT way to manage roles from Azure portal interface? I want to manage roles for my app by simple clicking, not writing configuration files manually. Azure AD interface have tonns of groups and roles settings and tabs, but still no easy way to use it in ASP.NET Core web app. I remember, like year ago I saw a way for using Azure AD groups as roles, but still it was using preview features, and was not simple to configure from portal and just use `[Authorize(Roles="MyGroupNameFromAD")]` in controller. Anything changed to simplicity in that way?